# Calculated Column formula between two tables using Python Script in Power Bi

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hi I am trying to multiple employees charge (Table1 i.e "Efforts") with billing hour (Table2 i.e "AnalystMaster")

Analyst Master:

[image]

Efforts:

[image]

Code Tried:

```
# Python:

import pandas as pd
for i in range(0,len(Efforts["Analyst_Name"])):
    for j in range(0,len(AnalystMaster["Analyst_Name"])):
        if (Efforts["Analyst_Name"][i] == AnalystMaster["Analyst_Name"][j]):
            Efforts["Cost"][i] =(Efforts["Hours"][i]*AnalystMaster["Charge_Rate"][j])
            continue
```

Help me with the python script I am getting error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implemented linear search now works fine.

df1 is Analyst Master and df2 is Efforts

```
# Python:
import pandas as pd

def linear_search(values, search_for):
    search_at = 0
    value = df1["Charge Rate"].mean()
    search_res = value

# Match the value with each data element    
    while search_at < len(values) and search_res is value:
        if values[search_at] == search_for:
            search_res = df1["Charge Rate"][search_at]
        else:
            search_at = search_at + 1

    return search_res

randomList = []
for i in range(0,len(df2["Analyst_Name"])):
    if df2["Analyst_Name"][i] in df1["Analyst_Name"].values:
        randomList.append(df2["Hours"][i]*linear_search(df1["Analyst_Name"],df2["Analyst_Name"][i]))
    else:
        randomList.append(df2["Hours"][i]*linear_search(df1["Analyst_Name"],df2["Analyst_Name"][i]))
        
df2["Cost"] = randomList
```

The above code does a for loop in df2 elements if present in df1 list, then calls linear search and returns the analyst charge and get multiplied by billing. Else not present multiplies with mean of charge with billing hour.